# program crashes halfway through, no idea why

Tags: java, exception, crash

heres what i got, take a look and see what you can find. eclipse says everything is good to go, but when i run it, i get to input the 5 numbers, then it asks the two lines about highest to lowest or vice versa, then crash before i can put my answer in. im at a loss.

these are the errorrs i see.   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at monty.intarray.main(intarray.java:25)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class intarray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number other than zero, then hit enter. Do this five times.");

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] array=new int[5];



       for (int whatever = 0; whatever < array.length;whatever++)

            array[whatever]=input1.nextInt();
            input1.close();
       System.out.println("Now tell me if you want to see those numbers sorted from lowest to highest, or highest to lowest.");
       System.out.println("Use the command 'lowest' without the single quotes or 'highest'.");

       Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);
       String answer = input2.next();
       input2.close();

       boolean finish;
       finish = loworhigh(answer);

       if (finish) {
           Arrays.sort(array);
           for (int a = array.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
               System.out.print(array[a] + " ");
           }
       }
       else {
           Arrays.sort(array);
           for (int b=0; b<=array.length; b++) {
               System.out.print(array[b] + " ");
           }
       }



       System.out.print(array[0] + ", ");
       System.out.print(array[1] + ", ");
       System.out.print(array[2] + ", ");
       System.out.print(array[3] + ", ");
       System.out.print(array[4] + ".");


  }

public static boolean loworhigh(String ans) {

    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("lowest")) return false;
    else  return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: a guess but for (int b=0; b<=array.length; b++) should be < array.length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call on for input1.close, it also closes System.In input stream along with the scanner.

To check if Scanner is still available you can try:

```
System.out.println(System.in.available());
```

And there is no way to re-open System.In

```
public void close() throws IOException --> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with this stream. The general contract of close is that it closes the input stream. A closed stream cannot perform input operations and **cannot be reopened.**
```

And thus it throws `NoSuchElementException`

To avoid this, don't close input1 and instead use the same Scanner object and accept as many inputs as required and finally close the Scanner.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that helped a lot. it works now, and i get my output correctly from lowest to highest but i get this error at the end even tho the program ran correctly.   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at monty.intarray.main(intarray.java:41)

Comment: ok i fixed it, disregard, problem solved, thanks so much for that scanner answer!